# Recovering Spring Boot Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'm running Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) and was in the middle of a Spring Boot course when an Eclipse update killed my Workspace.

After many hours of research on -clean, eclipse.ini edits, etc I decided to start a new workspace.  I have a local repo created on the HD and subclipse 1.10.13 plugin installed, so I knew my actual project was safe.

Problem is I can't get Maven to recreate the original structure of the project with the new project wizard (assuming this is what I need since a straight checkout was missing many directories/files.  Using the wizard the structure is still off and it creates a duplicate pom.xml file.

How do I get Maven to recreate the structure the way it was without creating  a duplicate pom.xml?

Comment: If your maven project is sound, then just copy the project files in your old workspace somewhere else and use the Import Existing Maven projects functionality to add it.  That should do it. (A word of advice - you may want to consider learning source control, to ensure that next time a disaster happens you can just revert to the latest commit)

Comment: okay, thanks that worked, any recommendations for solid resources on SC?

Comment: In a nutshell - learn git.  Github has some good documentation.  SO has http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/218/getting-started-with-git#t=201701170839303958967

Answer (score 0):

You can try to right click on your project, then from the context menu, click Configure > Convert to Maven project

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to start your Eclipse and Workspace with the start parameters [-clean -initialize](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)